# Backbone - Why doesn't a collection.reset trigger a model event?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm curious to find out why resetting a backbone collection doesn't fire a model event. However, it seems only logical to fire a model event when a model is physically being removed from a collection.

Is this intentional or am I missing something? If backbone doesn't do this sort of thing what's a good practice for delegating events like so.

Why does backbone not trigger a model event when its collection resets?

```
var TicketModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'crafty',
        email: 'dwq@dwqcqw.com'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.on("all", function(event){
            console.log(event)
        });
    }

});

var TicketCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TicketModel,

    });


var tickets = new TicketCollection([
    {
        name: 'halldwq'
    },
    {
        name: 'dascwq'
    },
    {
        name: 'dsacwqe'
    }

]);

tickets.reset();
```

Comment: fair enough, if that makes it clearer, thanks rimian

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Overriding Backbone method can cause pain when updating to another version.

Backbone stores an array of the models before the reset in options.previousModels, so just listen to the reset event and trigger a 'remove' event on those previous models:

```
collection.on('reset', function(col, opts){
   _.each(opts.previousModels, function(model){
        model.trigger('remove');
    });
});
```

That'd do the trick.

Answer (score 16):

This is the backbone reset function:

```
reset: function(models, options) {
  models  || (models = []);
  options || (options = {});
  for (var i = 0, l = this.models.length; i < l; i++) {
    this._removeReference(this.models[i]);
  }
  this._reset();
  this.add(models, _.extend({silent: true}, options));
  if (!options.silent) this.trigger('reset', this, options);
  return this;
},
```

We can ignore the last 3 lines because you don't supply any models to the reset-function. Also let's ignore the first 2 lines as well. So first we loop through the models in this collection and call the collection's `_removeReference(model)` method, it looks like this:

```
_removeReference: function(model) {
  if (this == model.collection) {
    delete model.collection;
  }
  model.off('all', this._onModelEvent, this);
},
```

What happens here is that we're removing the collection-property from the model object altogether and also remove the binding to this model's events. Next up we call the collection's `_reset()`-function, that looks like this:

```
_reset: function(options) {
  this.length = 0;
  this.models = [];
  this._byId  = {};
  this._byCid = {};
},
```

It just outright removes any reference to any models the collection has ever had.

What can we make from this? Well the collection `reset` -function in Backbone basically just circumvents all the official channels of removing models and does it all in hush hush secrecy, causing no other events than `reset` to be fired. So you want to fire the model's `remove` event for every model removed from a collection during reset? Easy! Just overwrite Backbone.Collection's reset-function like this:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  reset: function(models, options) {
    models  || (models = []);
    options || (options = {});

    for (var i = 0, l = this.models.length; i < l; i++) {
      this._removeReference(this.models[i]);
      // trigger the remove event for the model manually
      this.models[i].trigger('remove', this.models[i], this);
    }

    this._reset();
    this.add(models, _.extend({silent: true}, options));
    if (!options.silent) this.trigger('reset', this, options);
    return this;
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: very thorough answer. And enjoyable to read too! Thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem, it's always a great learning experience to go through the source code to find a solution for a question like this!

Comment: I wonder what the reasoning behind it is. A models 'remove' event bubbles up to the collection so why not the other way round?

Comment: I posted an issue here, who knows maybe we'll get a bit of background information as to why models are ignorant of their collection's behaviour. https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1521